# How to determine no of bytes of an instruction of 8085 microprocessor?

Tags: microprocessor, 8085

Is there any logical way to understand no of bytes corresponding to an instruction in 8085 microprocessor? e.g: MOV A,M is a one byte instruction, but how, I don't understand.

Or do I have to remember it?

Comment: Why do you need to know? I would write a program in assembly language, and let the assembler work it out for me. There will be some underlying structure, but it may help us to give an answer if we understand what it is you are trying to do. Edit: if this is only to pass an exam, then the bad news is the exam is a bit useless. I can't think of a time when I have needed to memorise this sort of stuff. In practice I'd use a datasheet or a tool (or write a program) which is more accurate than my memory

Comment: "Never memorize what you can look up" - Albert Einstein

Comment: @Octopus Especially when the processor in question has been out of production for over 20 years -- the chances that you'll ever use an 8085, let alone need to know how it encodes instructions, are essentially nil.

Comment: You don't have to remember it. You would always do assembly programming with a copy of the processor handbook by your side, or on another tab on your screen.

Comment: In exams, there are some question like no of byte corresponding to an Instruction or this information is needed to solve that question. But if there is some logic to find it (as answered by MarkU), then there is no issue with such type of question.

Comment: Just look it up in the table.

Comment: @Ranjan I've never taken such an exam and I would consider it very poor practice to set one.

Comment: *Many* years ago, I had to write bit banged serial ports in assembler (6502 and 6809 as I recall) that were timing invariant regardless of the data; that *did* require one to calculate the total number of bytes (and therefore clock cycles) involved. That had to take account of the fact that a branch used a different amount of cycles depending on whether the branch was taken or not.

Comment: @peter Smith - I started off writing machine code (no assembler :-) ) for MC6800 :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction format depends on the addressing mode.

Register-to-register instructions only need to know the opcode, the source register, and the destination register. Usually that much information can be encoded in one byte.

A Move-Immediate instruction needs 8 bits to store the immediate 8-bit data, plus the opcode and destination register, so that is a two-byte instruction.

A 16-bit move-immediate instruction (e.g. loading the HL register pair) requires 16-bits, plus the opcode and destination register encoding, so that is a three-byte instruction.

Comment: Hi @MarkU I am not able to understand how MOV A,M is one byte instruction. Here A: Accumulator M : memory 

I think the above definition does not cover such type of instructions.

Comment: If you think that, then you need to review the architecture of the 8085 some more. "M" refers to an indirect addressing mode, in which the current contents of the HL register pair are used as the memory address.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually rather simple, Any instruction e.g MOV A,B or MVI B,32H or MOV A,M is eventually converted to bits by the assembler and the No. of bits are calculated from that.
Thus for MOV A,M we have opcode 7E(HEX i.e 8bits), moreover A and M both are internal registers(M references HL pair, though HL pair contains a reference to memory and not data, but that doesn't change the fact that it points to HL). Thus we don't need any more bits.

Here the No. of Cycles is two, 1st for opcode fetch and 2nd for memory read to resolve the reference to memory.

Hence MOV A,M (7E) becomes 0111 1110.